# entrada de datos con (input) en python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código de clases que se ejecuta sin ningún problema, quiero hacer la entrada de datos utilizando la funcion `input` y que luego se visualice con `print` o `return`, pero no he podido hacerlo se me desconfigura cuando lo intento.

Agradecería orientación en el tema. ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?

```
#SuperClase, Clase Padre(esto se convierte en programacion en capas)
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, clv, nom, ed):
        self.clave = clv
        self.nombre = nom
        self.edad = ed
    def mostrarDatos(self,):
        print("Mostrando los Datos desde la SuperClase")
        print("CLAVE: ", self.clave)
        print("NOMBRE: ", self.nombre)
        print("EDAD: ", self.edad)

#CON ESTO CREAMOS LA HERENCIA
class Trabajador(Persona):
    def __init__(self, clv, nom, ed, suel):
        self.clave = clv
        self.nombre = nom
        self.edad = ed
        self.sueldo = suel
    def mostrarDatos(self,):
        print("____________________________________")
        print("Mostrando los Datos desde la SubClase")
        print("CLAVE: ", self.clave)
        print("NOMBRE: ", self.nombre)
        print("EDAD: ", self.edad)
        print("SUELDO: ", self.sueldo)
        # creando instancias (Objetos)

Administrador = Persona("AAMM45", "elias PARAMO", 35)
Empleado = Trabajador("AAMM45", "PEDRO PARAMO", 35, 2350500)
Administrador.mostrarDatos()
Empleado.mostrarDatos()
```

Comment: Hola, tal vez también puedas mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora. El uso de `input` es muy sencillo, me gustaría ver en qué te estás equivocando antes de dar una respuesta.

Comment: No entendí bien, deseas que los datos : "AAMM45", "elias PARAMO", 35 y "AAMM45", "PEDRO PARAMO", 35, 2350500 los ingreses a travez de un input?

Comment: cesar, gracias, he borrado lo que intentado, pero te digo he aplicado a los metodos el input, mostrarDatos por ejem.:

Comment: print= input("CLAVE: ", self.clave)

Comment: si Ariel, esa es la idea, que tenga que registrar lo datos con el modulo, si no que los pida.

Comment: que me pida los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, según entiendo por tus comentarios, algo como esto debería funcionar:

```
>>> class A():
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.x = None
...     self.y = None
...
...   def obtener_datos(self):
...     self.x = input('Valor de X: ')
...     self.y = input('Valor de Y: ')
...
...   def mostrar_datos(self):
...     print('X: ', self.x)
...     print('Y: ', self.y)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.mostrar_datos()
X:  None
Y:  None
>>> a.obtener_datos()
Valor de X: Cesar
Valor de Y: 100
>>> a.mostrar_datos()
X:  Cesar
Y:  100
```

Simplemente he creado el método `obtener_datos()` para usar el `input` y guardarlo en cada atributo. Solo tienes que llevarlo a tu ejemplo.

Comment: Cesar excelente, funciono, la inclusion de ese metodo obtener_datos, soluciona el problema de la entrada de datos.muy agradecido.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 si, como te decía el uso de `input` es muy sencillo. Como menciona Patricio en su respuesta, tal vez no se buena idea que incluyas en `input` en la clase.

Answer (score 1):

No me queda claro por que el `input` te trae problemas. O bien usas el mecanismo de @Cesar o si no quieres encapsular los inputs en la clase, normalmente podrías hacer esto:

```
clv = input("Ingrese la clave:")
nom = input("Ingrese el nombre:")
ed = input("Ingrese la edad:")
Administrador = Persona(clv, nom, ed)

clv = input("Ingrese la clave:")
nom = input("Ingrese el nombre:")
ed = input("Ingrese la edad:")
suel = input("Ingrese el sueldo:")
Empleado = Trabajador(clv , nom , ed , suel )

Administrador.mostrarDatos()
Empleado.mostrarDatos()
```

Comment: si Patricio los dos tienen la razon. queda claro. estaba enfocando mal el problema. gracias

Answer (score 0):

si de algo te sirve yo tenia el mismo problema y realice algo asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prodrias pegar el codigo en vez de colocar una imagen? Asi es mejor para todos

Comment: OK Sr.     
class datos:
    def __init__(self,nom,eda,tel):
        self.nom=input("dame tu nombre")
        self.eda=input("dame tu edad")
        self.tel=input("dame tu telefono")
    def juntar (self):
        print("hola te llamas {} y tienes {} años y tu telefono es {}".format(self.nom,self.eda,self.tel))
persona1=datos("miguel",32,23)
persona1.nom
persona1.eda
persona1.tel
persona1.juntar()

Comment: Si sabes que puedes editar tu respueta verdad? Sobre todo siendo python, que depende de estar en varias lineas y de la indentacinon, el codigo asi como lo pegaste es de poca ayuda